# Typescript conditional type on generic string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a type `CodeGenBlock` and I want to have some properties be dynamically added to the type of the object depending on whether the `type` is `root`, `null` or something else :

```
type InternalCodeGenTypes = 'root' | 'null';

export type CodeGenBlock<
    In extends string,
    T extends In | InternalCodeGenTypes = In | InternalCodeGenTypes
> = {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    signifier: string;
    type: T;
    opts?: CodeGenBlock<T>[];
    data: T extends 'null' ? never : string | (() => string);
};

const myCodeBlock: CodeGenBlock<"userDefinedA" | "userDefinedB"> = {
    type: "null",
    // data is never never, I don't know why though
    // I was wondering on on how to get the actual value of type without having to pass "null" as a parameter to CodeGenBlock
    }
```

I tried doing generic and testing it with `extends`, but that doesn't check against the actually passed value, just against the string list, which always returns true. I am confused on how I could do this.

The passed In type is defined by the user of the software, so I cannot pre-define and exposing 'root' and 'null' also doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add code to make this a [mcve] of your problem?  I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with `CodeGenBlock`.

Comment: Ya not sure what you are trying to do. What's the purpose of the In type?

Comment: @jcalz @Tim I need to modify the shape of the `CodeGenBlock Object` based on the value provided to the `type` property of said object. I was wondering whether it would be possible to do so without having to pass it explicitly as a parameter to the `CodeGenBlock type`

Comment: @Tim In type is to take the user input and allow it to be extended with the interal parameters of the library